# Create and seed .torrent using command line

Tags: centos, bittorrent, transmission

I want to create and seed a torrent file from console (CentOS), so I've installed and started transmission, but the .torrent file doesn't seed:

```
yum install transmission-cli transmission-daemon -y
mkdir ~/p2p
cp filedir/ ~/p2p
cd ~/p2p
transmission-create filedir/ -t udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80
transmission-daemon -c ~/p2p
```

Also, changed Downloads and Incomplete folder to ~/p2p in settings.json

This is on a server with WHM/cPanel installed, so the ports might be the problem?
BTW, I'm trying to download the .torrent from another PC, and it gives me no seeders.